# BASE_DIR returning settings path and not project path (django 1.10)

Tags: django, django-settings, django-1.10

I am currently setting up my settings files for Django 1.10 as per Two Scoops For Django 1.8 preferred settings files set up.

my base.py settings file is:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

the BASE_DIR is returning the following path:

```
/Devs/projects/captain_log/src/cap_log
```

my file tree:

```
|--Virtual Env Folder
    |--src(django project)/
       |--cap_log(django config)/
          |--init.py
          |--urls.py
          |--wsgi.py
          |--settings/
              |-- init.py
              |-- base.py (all settings located here)
              |-- development.py
              |-- production.py
              |-- etc.
```

I am under the assumption that the BASE_DIR is supposed to return:

```
/Devs/projects/captain_log/src/
```

I am asking because my STATIC_DIRS is also returning:

```
/Devs/projects/captain_log/src/cap_log/static
```

instead of:

```
 /Devs/projects/captain_log/src/static
```

Can someone please advise to a solution or correction to what I am doing.
It is also effecting template paths, collectstatic, Media Path, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try one more `dirname` call

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

The first dirname gives you settings, the second gives you the config folder, the third will put you in the parent directory

```
__file__ # is the current file location
os.path.abspath(__file__) # locates you on the file structure
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # gives you the directory of the file at the supplied filepath
```

The default assumption is you are using a `settings.py` file rather than a directory, so you are one directory shallow in the original config

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: I moved my settings.py file into a settings/ folder to hold all my setting files. And all hell broke loose. Adding one more `os.path.dirname` to the existing value fixed it for me. `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`